# How to change row color in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using datatables and currently stuck in changing a row to another color if value = INACTIVE, already tried many things but it has really weird error, my codes are :

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        if (data[9] = "INACTIVE") {
            $(row).addClass("yellow");
        } else {
            $(row).addClass("white");
        }
    }
```

This code change all color row, but i want only change value INACTIVE

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add more information or create demo of your datatables code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

In your if statement use `==` instead of `=`.

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    if (data[9] == "INACTIVE") {
        $(row).addClass("yellow");
    } else {
        $(row).addClass("white");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add one more and make it `===`

Answer (score 0):

In the condition, you are assigning the value `"INACTIVE"` to the `data[9]` instead of comparing the value. Subsequently, the condition only checks whether `data[9]` has *some* value, which is true, and class `.yellow` is always added.

So the condition should be like this `if (data[9] == "INACTIVE")` or rather `if (data[9] === "INACTIVE")` to perform check without type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you are using a single '=' which is used for assignment. You should use double '=' to compare if the value is the same and triple '=' to compare if the value and the data types are the same.

You are also only checking index 9 of data. In your function you seem to also be passing in the index, you should instead change your code to something like this.

```
if (  data[ dataIndex ] === "INACTIVE" )
```